# Try all the combinations (cases) Function

Tags: python

I've been struggling with the [cutting stock problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem) for a while, and I need to do a funcion that given an array of values, gives me an array of array for all the possible combinations.

I trying to do this function, but (as everything in python), I think someone must have done it better :).

I think the name of the function is combination. Does anyone know whats the best way to do this, and what's the best module and function for this

P.s. I have read some papers on the matter, but the matematical terms dazzle me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> x = range(3)
>>> list(permutations(x))
[(0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 2, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 1, 0)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> list(combinations('abcd', 2))
```